# On every page footer margin is different

Tags: html, css, haml, sass, footer

I have web page, and i must to stick footer on bottom of page. I have code for you here: 
1) http://jsfiddle.net/6P3Ag/
2) http://jsfiddle.net/bmzgp/

Also please see preview on jsfiddle, like http://jsfiddle.net/6P3Ag/embedded/result/ it is important (height is another)

**But why i get different margin-top between footer and wrapper on each page? What's wrong?**

And  a little bit of footer code:

```
.footer{
  position: relative;
  margin: 150px 0 0 0;
  @include gradient-background(bottom, $gr1, $gr2);
  width: 100%;
  height: 144px;
  clear: both;
}
```

Also i use sass+haml...

Comment: I would suggest creating a much simpler fiddle with less content, which still replicates the problem. You might even see the problem yourself in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just gave it a quick look but I think it's an issue with the height of your `wrapper` div. I removed `height:100%` from the wrapper class on both examples and it looks like the footer is now uniformly sized across them.